# Rowaction dropdown button text

Tags: abp

is there a way not to display a text on button like shown below. We want to have icon only button to save space. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: "Tooltips" might be what you're looking for. You can do this easier by using ABP Tag helper: https://bootstrap-taghelpers.abp.io/Components/Tooltips

Comment: thanks but that's not what we are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a whitespace into your `text` property in `rowAction` you can see the icon only. Otherwise by default datatable append an `Action` text.

```js
        columnDefs: [
            {
                rowAction: {
                    text: ' ', //add a white space
                  //...
```

[image: Icon]

Comment: Thank you very much, that was tried but how may a user guess the white space. You saved really much time.